# RAID0 ; Need to restore configuration

Tags: raid

I have a Dell Poweredge workstation with Ubuntu server installed in it. Hard disks are configured with RAID0. While using the RAID controller setup (after restart), I removed one of the six hard disks, and now it says that one physical disk is offline, and that a foreign configuration is present. How do I recover it back to the previous configuration?

(Just to be clear, all that I did was to pull a disk during the RAID configuration prompt).

Answer (score 1):

The big danger of using a RAID0 configuration is that if a disk fails (or the storage controller loses its configuration), you can say goodbye to all your data.

If you removed a drive, automatically the storage controller will mark it as foreign because *a priori* it doesn't know what is that disk (even if it's the same you removed just for a second).

However, nowadays RAID controllers are smart enough to *import* a configuration. It's important that any data weren't written to a disk at any time, though.

If at boot time you are propmpted by the RAID controller to **import configuration**, try to do it. That's the process where the controller identifies foreign disks and try to add them to an array. If you're not prompted, try entering the RAID controller configuration with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (if I remember right for PowerEdge systems).

If it doesn't work, bad luck. It's always recommendable to use a RAID-5 minimally for these cases.